# ModelMapper: mapping abstract classes during runtime

Tags: java, object-object-mapping, modelmapper

I am using ModelMapper Framework (http://modelmapper.org/) for mapping objects in Java.
I have encountered a problem while mapping concrete classes (DTO to Entites) containing abstract classes.

Example:
Task has a list of AbstractItems. 
AbstractItems are Question and Criteria.

```
public class TaskDTO {
   ...
   private List<AbstractItemDTO> items;
}
```

Mapping method:

```
// task is an TaskDTO object
return getModelMapper().map(task, TaskEntity.class);
```

ModelMapper tries to create a new instance of AbstractItem, which throws an exception.
Is there a way to map the abstract classes during the runtime?

Like QuestionDTO -> Question, CriteriaDTO ->Criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this problem with ModelMapper. Thus, I switched over to Dozer. 
 
**Dozer** is a great tool for object mapping in Java. And it is really easy to use as well.
You can define the corresponding mapping classes in a XML-file.

Here's a link to the documentation. http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html

**My Solution with Spring**

*dozer-bean.xml*

```
<bean class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="mappingFiles">
            <list>
                <value>META-INF/mapping/dozer-config.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

*dozer-config.xml*

```
<mapping>
            <class-a>com.packagename.dto.QuestionDTO</class-a>
            <class-b>com.packagename.entities.core.Question</class-b>
</mapping>
<mapping>
        <class-a>com.packagename.dto.CriteriaDTO</class-a>
        <class-b>com.packagename.entities.core.Criteria</class-b>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem and solved this with:

```
public void configure(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    modelMapper.typeMap(QuestionDto.class, AbstractItem.class)
            .setConverter(converterWithDestinationSupplier(Question::new));
    modelMapper.typeMap(CriteriaDto.class, AbstractItem.class)
            .setConverter(converterWithDestinationSupplier(Criteria::new));
}

private <S, D> Converter<S, D> converterWithDestinationSupplier(Supplier<? extends D> supplier ) {
    return ctx -> ctx.getMappingEngine().map(ctx.create(ctx.getSource(), supplier.get()));
}
```

Converter uses supplier to create required instance and then uses right typeMap (QuestionDto -> Question or CriteriaDto -> Criteria) to map all properties.

Answer (score 1):

Where a kotlin solution with ModelMapper

DTOs (aka source class)

```
abstract class BaseRequirementDTO()
class AttributeRequirementDTO(

        var attribute: Attribute = Attribute.STRENGTH,
        var attributeValue: Long = 10

) : BaseRequirementDTO()
class LevelRequirementDTO(

        var requiredLevel: Long = 1

) : BaseRequirementDTO()
```

My Models (aka destination class)

```
abstract class BaseRequirement() : Model()
class AttributeRequirement(

        var attribute: Attribute = Attribute.STRENGTH,
        var attributeValue: Long = 10

) : BaseRequirement()
class LevelRequirement(

        var requiredLevel: Long = 1

) : BaseRequirement()
```

Mapper configuration

```
val mapper = ModelMapper()
mapper.configuration.matchingStrategy = MatchingStrategies.STRICT
mapper.createTypeMap(BaseRequirement::class.java, BaseRequirementDTO::class.java)
mapper.typeMap(AttributeRequirementDTO::class.java, BaseRequirement::class.java)
        .setProvider { request -> mapper.map(request.source, AttributeRequirement::class.java) }
mapper.typeMap(LevelRequirementDTO::class.java, BaseRequirement::class.java)
        .setProvider { request -> mapper.map(request.source, LevelRequirement::class.java) }
```

ModelMapper version: **2.3.7**

https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/182#issuecomment-660965119