# Failed to instantiate instance of destination [subclassDTO]. Ensure that [subclassDTO] has a non-private no-argument constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance, dto, modelmapper

Im working on a Springboot App exposing some endpoints that do not return the original Entities but they return their DTO. To map all the entities i am working using "org.modelmapper" version: 0.7.4 and project lombok to avoid implement getters, setters and some another utilities.

Everything worked perfectly until I had to map a list of subclasses on a entity. The source entity is like this (i removed some properties and hibernate annotations because they are not necessary in the example):

```java
package com.pfi.repository.entity.sport;

import com.pfi.repository.entity.address.Address;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SportPlace {

    private Long id;
    private List<AbstractSportField> sportFields;
}
```

The destination DTO is:

```java
package dto.sport;

import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class SportPlaceDTO {

    private Long id;
    private List<AbstractSportFieldDTO> sportFields;
}
```

Both AbstractSportFieldDTO and AbstractSportField are abstract classes that with two possible subclasses:

```java
package dto.sport;

import dto.reserve.AbstractReserveDTO;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class AbstractSportFieldDTO {

    protected Long id;
    protected List<AbstractReserveDTO> reserves;
    public AbstractSportFieldDTO() {
    }

    public AbstractSportFieldDTO(Long id, List<AbstractReserveDTO> reserves) {
        this.id = id;
        this.reserves = reserves;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public AbstractSportFieldDTO setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }


    public List<AbstractReserveDTO> getReserves() {
        return reserves;
    }

    public AbstractSportFieldDTO setReserves(List<AbstractReserveDTO> reserves) {
        this.reserves = reserves;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The first DTO subclass is:

```java
package dto.sport;


import dto.reserve.AbstractReserveDTO;

import java.util.List;

public class ComboSportFieldDTO extends AbstractSportFieldDTO {

    private List<SportFieldDTO> sportFields;

    public ComboSportFieldDTO(List<SportFieldDTO> sportFields) {
        this.sportFields = sportFields;
    }

    public ComboSportFieldDTO(Long id, List<AbstractReserveDTO> reserves, List<SportFieldDTO> sportFields) {
        super(id, reserves);
        this.sportFields = sportFields;
    }

    public ComboSportFieldDTO() {
        super();
    }

    public List<SportFieldDTO> getSportFields() {
        return sportFields;
    }

    public void setSportFields(List<SportFieldDTO> sportFields) {
        this.sportFields = sportFields;
    }
}
```

The second DTO subclass is:

```java
package dto.sport;

import dto.reserve.AbstractReserveDTO;

import java.util.List;

public class SportFieldDTO extends AbstractSportFieldDTO {

    private Boolean joineable;

    public SportFieldDTO(Long id, List<AbstractReserveDTO> reserves, Boolean joineable) {
        super(id, reserves);
        this.joineable = joineable;
    }

    public SportFieldDTO() {
        super();
    }

    public Boolean getJoineable() {
        return joineable;
    }

    public void setJoineable(Boolean joineable) {
        this.joineable = joineable;
    }
}
```

Then the Entities are:

```java
package com.pfi.repository.entity.sport;

import com.pfi.repository.entity.reserve.AbstractReserve;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class AbstractSportField {

    protected Long id;
    protected List<AbstractReserve> reserves;

    public AbstractSportField(Long id, List<AbstractReserve> reserves) {
        this.id = id;
        this.reserves = reserves;
    }

    public AbstractSportField() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public AbstractSportField setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public List<AbstractReserve> getReserves() {
        return reserves;
    }

    public AbstractSportField setReserves(List<AbstractReserve> reserves) {
        this.reserves = reserves;
        return this;
    }

}
```

The first subclass is:

```java
package com.pfi.repository.entity.sport;

import com.pfi.repository.entity.reserve.AbstractReserve;

import java.util.List;

public class ComboSportField extends AbstractSportField {

    private List<SportField> sportFields;

    public ComboSportField(Long id, List<AbstractReserve> reserves, List<SportField> sportFields) {
        super(id, reserves);
        this.sportFields = sportFields;
    }

    public ComboSportField(){
        super();
    }

    public List<SportField> getSportFields() {
        return sportFields;
    }

    public ComboSportField setSportFields(List<SportField> sportFields) {
        this.sportFields = sportFields;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And the last subclass is:

```java
package com.pfi.repository.entity.sport;

import com.pfi.repository.entity.reserve.AbstractReserve;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.util.List;

public class SportField extends AbstractSportField {

    private Boolean joineable;

    public SportField(Long id, List<AbstractReserve> reserves, Boolean joineable) {
        super(id, reserves);
        this.joineable = joineable;
    }

    public SportField(){
        super();
    }

    public Boolean getJoineable() {
        return joineable;
    }

    public SportField setJoineable(Boolean joineable) {
        this.joineable = joineable;
        return this;
    }
}
```

When i try to map an instance of SportPlace to SportPlaceDTO like this:

```java
modelMapper.map(sportPlace, SportPlaceDTO.class)
```

That de sportPlace contains the given 6 Sportfields that are instances of subclasses. The model mapper throws (on the 6 elements of the list):

Failed to instantiate instance of destination dto.sport.AbstractSportFieldDTO. Ensure that dto.sport.AbstractSportFieldDTO has a non-private no-argument constructor.

Reading about how can i map subclasses on modelmapper i found setting TypeMap, that can set a specific mapping on a class like this:

modelMapper.createTypeMap(ComboSportField.class, ComboSportFieldDTO.class);

For that reason i created a builder to config the model mapper like this

```java
package com.pfi.repository.builder;

import com.pfi.repository.entity.*;;
import dto.reserve.*;
import dto.sport.*;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.modelmapper.convention.MatchingStrategies;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MapperBuilder {

    public ModelMapper buildModelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        mapEntitiesToDTO(modelMapper);
        mapDTOToEntities(modelMapper);
        return modelMapper;
    }

    private void mapEntitiesToDTO(final ModelMapper modelMapper){
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(ComboSportField.class, ComboSportFieldDTO.class);
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(SportField.class, SportFieldDTO.class);
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(Reserve.class, ReserveDTO.class);
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(AppReserve.class, AppReserveDTO.class);

    }
    private void mapDTOToEntities(final ModelMapper modelMapper){
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(ComboSportFieldDTO.class, ComboSportField.class);
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(SportFieldDTO.class, SportField.class);
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(ReserveDTO.class, Reserve.class);
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(AppReserveDTO.class, AppReserve.class);
    }
}
```

And i use the builder when i create the controller like this:

```java
@Autowired
    protected MapperBuilder mapperBuilder;

    BaseController(){
        this.getLogger();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void buildMapper(){
        modelMapper = mapperBuilder.buildModelMapper();
    }
```

I don't know what else I can do to be able map the subclasses.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this issue with the help of some friends and another questions on this site.

***My solution***

Another Dev posted an issue similar to mine [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111875/modelmapper-mapping-abstract-classes-during-runtime).

This post recomends the use of `typeMap` (but not as I used it) with a "converter" declaring. When a Subclass tries to map to `AbstractClassDTO` it must instantiate a `subclassDTO`.

Like this:

```java
public ModelMapper buildModelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    mapEntitiesToDTO(modelMapper);
    mapDTOToEntities(modelMapper);
    return modelMapper;
}

private void mapEntitiesToDTO(final ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(ComboSportField.class, AbstractSportFieldDTO.class)
        .setConverter(converterWithDestinationSupplier(ComboSportFieldDTO::new));
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(SportField.class, AbstractSportFieldDTO.class)
        .setConverter(converterWithDestinationSupplier(SportFieldDTO::new));
}

private void mapDTOToEntities(final ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(ComboSportFieldDTO.class, AbstractSportField.class)
        .setConverter(converterWithDestinationSupplier(ComboSportField::new));
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(SportFieldDTO.class, AbstractSportField.class)
        .setConverter(converterWithDestinationSupplier(SportField::new));
}

private < S, D > Converter < S, D > converterWithDestinationSupplier(Supplier << ? extends D > supplier) {
    return ctx - > ctx.getMappingEngine().map(ctx.create(ctx.getSource(), supplier.get()));
}
```

When I tested this configuration it still didn't work. Then I found that the same dev that posted the last question posted an issue on `modelmapper` GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/130). And the last comment reports that `typeMap` with inheritance had been released on ModelMapper **1.0.0** and I found that I was using the version **0.7.4**.

So I updated the version to the current **(2.3.5)** and this started to work. [Link to maven repo.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper)

I hope that my description can help someone with the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: This solution helped me. Updating the modelmapper version solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i have just experienced the same issue.

In my case the class for which modelmapper was complaining of a lack of public constructor was actually referenced as property inside another DTO class, mapped elsewhere, for which the public constructor was effectively not explicitly declared.

I have added such public constructor and this resolved the issue for me.